# Turkish Language Encoding Problem in R Studio

Tags: r, encoding, turkish

I am using R Studio for creating plots for economic variables. But in our language when you don't use our specific letters as "ğ,ş,ı,ü,ç" the word means different. And even sometimes it means swearing. I can't create graphs with this letters. I tried to use this command;

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Turkish")
```

The output is

```
OS reports request to set locale to "Turkish" cannot be honored[1] ""
```

How can i solve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 support in R on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726261/utf-8-support-in-r-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem and your system is Mac. First open terminal and then copy this code:

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

paste and run. I solved. I hope it works for your system, too.